Taking Homogeneous Elements in the Chevalley Shephard Todd Theorem
I am interested in the Chevalley Shephard Todd Theorem. Here, $V$ is a finite dimensional complex vector space. Let $G\subset GL(V)$ be a finite subgroup. Then, $Sym(V)^G$ is isomorphic as a $k$-algebra to a polynomial ring if and only if $G$ is generated by pseudoreflections.
All the sources I can find prove the only if direction when $Sym(V)^G$ is generated by homogeneous algebraically independent elements. But I was wondering, if we only know that $Sym(V)^G$ is generated by algebraically independent elements, is it possible to recover that $Sym(V)^G$ is generated by homogeneous elements easily?
I am aware of the following post but I don't believe the answers given answer my question (I looked in the original Shephard Todd paper and they seem to assume that everything is homogeneous).
Chevalley-Shephard-Todd theorem
In general: if $R\subset k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is a graded subalgebra isomorphic to a polynomial ring (not necessarily a graded isomorphism), can we take the generators of $R$ to be homogeneous (with respect to the grading of $k[x_1,...,x_n]$) and algebraically independent?
